# Customizing the notification-area toggles in Lollipop

Tags: nexus-5, 5.0-lollipop

In Lollipop, when I open the notification area (down-swipe from the top), and press the top right "user" icon, I get a set of toggles for some features: Wifi, Bluetooth, Airplane mode, Auto-rotate, Flashlight, Location, Cast screen, Hotspot.

Is there any way I can customize those toggles?

Specifically, I'm looking to add a toggle for my account syncing, so I can disable it over slow networks, and re-enable when I'm back on a fast wifi.

Comment: AFAIK, the stock ROM doesn't allow customization for that area.

Comment: @AndrewT. yes, it seems you are correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wasn't able to find any way of doing it via the stock ROM, and it seems like there is none. The second best solution I found was an application, [Power Toggles](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.painless.pc&hl=en), that adds toggles to the notification screen itself.

Comment: Good find - thanks! This also works well as a fill in for the media player buttons (play/pause, next, and previous) that sadly disappeared from the lock screen with the upgrade to Lollipop.

Comment: Additional note on the media player buttons: the one difference I see from the Kit Kat default media player buttons is that this only works with one app at a time, allowing you to select which app you want it to control.

Comment: @DunPeal [Power Toggles](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.painless.pc&hl=en) is not in the app store anymore, can you please share the apk ?